# Oscillator that only responds if two frequencies are present

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, nonlinear-system

I'm looking for a differential equation that responds to an driving force and which only responds if the driving force is a superposition of two frequencies?

As a counterpoint, a [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) will respond most when it is driven by a force which has the same frequency as the oscillator. That is, when the force is in resonance with the oscillator.

I'd like to know if there is a differential equation which involves a driving force which for which the solution has the largest response when the driving force is the sum of two frequencies, such as $sin{\omega_1t} + sin{\omega_2t}$ but not when any one of the frequencies is present without the other. So for instance the solution would not respond much to $sin{\omega_1t}$ or $sin{\omega_2t}$ by themselves.

Just to be precise, let me define the response of a solution to a driving force as the long term mean of the square of the solution, $\int_T^\infty x(t)^2 dt$ where $x(t)$ is the solution of the differential equation. Also, for this definition to make sense, the driving force has to have a bounded amplitude so that if $f(t)$ is the driving force, it has to be above and below two constants for all time.

Comment: Can $x$ be a three-dimensional vector, or does it have to be a scalar?

Comment: Do you already have something that responds to both but without the condition of "not when one of the frequencies is present without the other"? Just two peaks.

Comment: A harmonic oscillator tuned to the average frequency will respond equally to both. But it will also respond to either one.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I would prefer it to be a scalar, but would be interested to see what a vector solution would look like too.

Comment: Not the average, I meant take the figure at sinusoidal driving force and have two sharp peaks. That would respond to either frequency, not require some of both.

Comment: I'm just thinking of a brute-force solution: the first two coordinates are harmonic oscillators tuned to the desired frequencies, and the third coordinate is their product.

Comment: @Chris Culter thus, converting this 3D system into a single differential equation would yield a 6th degree ODE ? What is the opinion of the OP about that ?